# Convert a categorical column in so many columns as factors in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this one, where there might be more than one numerical column and more than one categorical column. In this case, there is only one of each class.

[image]

I would like to create a new data frame where new columns are created, each of them by one single factor of the initial V2 variable, as you can see here:

[image]

I've been searching this forum and found some questions related to mine but with boolean variables.

I am sure the code would be extraordinarily easy, but somehow I cannot find the correct one. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unstack()`

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = 1:6,
                 V2 = rep(c("DC1", "DC2"), each = 3),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

unstack(df)
#  DC1 DC2
#1   1   4
#2   2   5
#3   3   6
```

Comment: Thanks @markus. Imagine I have other categorical column (V3). How can I unstack it by using V2 as reference?

Comment: @antecessor If this answer solved the problem, you might accept it. Please ask another question and give an example of your data (no picture).

Comment: In my first two lines I describe my data as having more than 1 categorical column. Lets say I have a new column V3 = rep(c("A", B"), each = 3). How could I unstack the data frame using V2?

Comment: The problem I'm having is to imagine what the desired output looks like. You gave an example above and `unstack()` does the trick. Maybe you want this: `stats::reshape(data = df, timevar = "V3", idvar = c("V1"), direction = "wide")` or maybe this: `stats::reshape(data = df, timevar = "V2", idvar = c("V1"), direction = "wide")`. I guess neither of the two will serve your needs but how could I know.